# newSingleThreadExecutor() method in Executors Class

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, executorservice

The definition for above method is " Creates an Executor that uses a single worker thread operating off an unbounded queue."

I have seen examples which uses above method for "execute multiple instances of a method with different inputs in parallel" by adding different tasks in data structure like "Set" or "List" and calling method `invokeAll()`

Here I am confused about one thing : If the above method creates only a single worker thread, How is it possible to run the tasks in parallel ?

Of course, there are other methods like `newCachedThreadPool()`, `newFixedThreadPool(int numberOfThreads)`- Here many number of threads are created to run in parallel, if needed.

Comment: This is the Java doc from Oracle site:
Creates an Executor that uses a single worker thread operating off an unbounded queue. (Note however that if this single thread terminates due to a failure during execution prior to shutdown, a new one will take its place if needed to execute subsequent tasks.) Tasks are guaranteed to execute sequentially, and no more than one task will be active at any given time. Unlike the otherwise equivalent newFixedThreadPool(1) the returned executor is guaranteed not to be reconfigurable to use additional threads.

Comment: Can you give an example where you see the code is uses which executes in parallel?

Comment: If you want to start threads in parallel you don't need an executor

Comment: @Turing85 - Yes, what is your point?

Comment: @Turing85 - then look up the Java doc for this method newSingleThreadExecutor(). I am only quoting it said.

Comment: @Minh Kieu: So to run different instances of same method in parallel, I need to use the 'newCachedThreadPool()' or 'newFixedThreadPool(int numberOfThreads)' with 'invokeAll()' method. Right ?

Comment: @karra Depends. `invokeAll(...)` takes a `Collection<? extends Callable>` returns a `List<Future>` to be checked for results. If you just want to execute code without obtaining a return value, you probably want to `èxecute(...)` them. But I would actually recommend a [`ForkJoinPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) since this pool has work stealing built in.

Comment: @karra - you just need to create a newFixedThreadPool(int numberOfThreads) then submit your runnable and it will start running in parallel. Obviously, if you only specify 1 thread then multiple submitted tasks will not be run in parallel.

Comment: @RomanC You mean to say that I can do by using the threads but not the executors ? But I have studied that executors are better in managing the life cycle of threads and managing the overheads

Comment: @Turing85 - I am not disagreeing with you. I think we are talking of the same thing.

Comment: @MinhKieu whoops. Got your point just now. I misunderstood you =) sorry. The corresponding comments will self-destruct shortly.

Comment: @karra this is true and one of the reasons why `Executor`s were created. You probably want to take a look at [this tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html). It describes the different executors and how to work with them.

Comment: @karra What prevents you to manage them yourself, the word *better* or *worse* is ambiguous. You can't give a concrete answer to the specific problem.

Comment: @Turing85: I think 'ForkJoinPool' in general used for particular set of problems like Recursion(Divide and Conquer) or Can it be applied to any problem?

Comment: @Karra it is specialized for D&C-Tasks, but can be used like any other `ExecutorService` (since it implements this interface). The benefit is the built-in work stealing (aka. load balancer).

Comment: @MinhKieu: So does it really make any sense to use `invokeAll()` with the `newSingleThreadExecutor()` ?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to run more than one task at a time using the `newSingleThreadExecutor`:

`ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();`

But, it has a work queue in which you can put lot of tasks, these tasks simply wait in the queue to be executed and are executed one by one by the single thread in this executor.